# How to import classes in groovy?

Tags: java, groovy, import, classpath

I found many answers on this topic but still be confused...

What I want to achive:

in /groovy/com/a/package/A.groovy

```
package com.a.package

class A{
    public A(){}
    ...
}
```

in /another/folder/of/the/server/executableScript.groovy

```
import com.a.package.A

def a = new A()
```

If I'm not missing something very basic this should work if the class is on the classpath. It should even work if the file extension is .class instead of .groovy. When I try:

```
/* gives me 'unable to resolve class'
import com.a.package.A

def a = new A()
*/
def cl = (URLClassLoader) this.class.getClassLoader()

for(URL url : cl.getURLs()){
    println url.toString()
}
```

It returns me a long list of URLs where mine is one of the values as an asolute path. Do I miss something?

Comment: Most likely your `class A` is in fact not getting compiled and added to the classpath. Show your build control file.

Comment: I bet you didn't add the `/groovy` folder to the classpath.

Comment: it's not about import (actually NOTHING gets "imported"), it's about a mess in your classpath

Comment: It's true @daggett I didn't add ```/groovy``` explicitly. For testing purposes I added the acctual path to the file, like so ```E:/groovy/com/a/package/A.groovy```. @chrylis -cautiouslyoptimistic If it wouldn't be added to the classpath woudn't that mean that it shouldn't be displayed when printing the classpath urls?

Comment: `import com.a.package.A` is a command to find file `com/a/package/A` with extension `class` or `groovy` in folders or jars listed in classpath. So, you must add a folder `e:/groovy` to classpath

Comment: thanks @daggett, have read the same here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/findingclasses.html Classpath can only contain folders and archives... bad mistake... thanks nontheless